# How to access metrics of streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.4.

I'm migrating a Spark Streaming application to Structured Streaming.

I am working on generation metrics for each batch and I want to have control over the stats for each micro batch. I am interested in `processingDelay`, `schedulingDelay` and `totalDelay` metrics of each microBatch and where to find them in Structured Streaming.

I tried the following approach but it doesn't generate any stats.

```
val recentBatchInfos = new StatsReportListener(60).batchInfos
val numberOfRecords = recentBatchInfos.map(_.numRecords).sum
```

Can anyone tell how to use have control over stats and generate the corresponding metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation model of Spark Structured Streaming and Spark Streaming are different. Structured Streaming uses `Dataset` data abstraction while Spark Streaming uses RDD API directly. The available metrics in Structured Streaming are then different.

You should really use [StreamingQueryListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener) which is the monitoring interface:

> Interface for listening to events related to StreamingQueries.

`onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit` gives you access to the current [StreamingQueryProgress](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress) with all the current streaming metrics.

Consult [Reporting Metrics programmatically using Asynchronous APIs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#reporting-metrics-programmatically-using-asynchronous-apis) in the official documentation of Spark Structured Streaming.